# Are there regular Gujarati fonts for Ubuntu?

Tags: fonts, language-support

All the fonts supplied with Ubuntu Gujarati Language Support have fancy typfaces. The conventional typeface which is seen in all the newspapers is not supplied with Ubuntu. There is a third-party Gujarati font called Saraswati5 which has conventional typeface, but this font doesn't render correctly in Ubuntu. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try [This](http://saumil.net/howto/gujfont/Saumil_guj2.ttf). 
 Download and open as usual, click "Install font"

Comment: Very good fonts, but since they are not utf fonts, they won't work with Ubuntu's Gujarati keyboard layout. They only work with English keyboard layout and need to be installed on every single PC for the text to be visible.